# CSS won't apply to HTML tag for some reason

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML file as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gothic+A1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

        <title>My Name</title>
    </head>

    <div class = "main">
        <h1 id="my-name">Hey, I'm John!</h1>
        <div class="about">
            <p>Bio goes here </p>
        </div>

        <div class="projects">
            <h1 id="project-section-title">Projects</h1>
            <dl class="row">
                <div class="project">
                    .
                    .
                    .
                </div>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

I want to style to whole page to have a certain background so I added in

```
html {
    font-family: 'Gothic A1', sans-serif;
    background-color: #151515;
    color: #8a8a8a;
}
```

to the CSS, but nothing will happen when I save it.

Comment: Did you save the CSS file in the same folder of the HTML file?

Comment: @RHShanks92 yes, other changes are saving as well i.e. layout

Comment: They're likely being overridden by something in the two later stylesheets. Try moving your stylesheet under the others in the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Bootstrap specifies the `background-color: #fff` property for the `body` element. Use the `body` selector in the CSS file instead of the `html` one.